wavy pattern in FFT of image
I'm trying to diagnose poor image quality from a cheap camera. In addition to normal noise and blocky jpg compression, there's a pebble-like quality to them. Trying to understand this, I took the fft of the images. Across the frequency domain, there's a "tiger stripe" pattern that I've never seen before.
The same scene taken with different camera of similar quality (both are cheap security cameras from the same mfg.) doesn't have this.
Any ideas what might cause this?

